# Comparison of double sums of sequences with asymptotically close terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_{nk}\}_{n,k=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_{nk}\}_{n,k=1}^\infty$ be two sequences of positive numbers such that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{nk}}{b_{nk}}=1.$$
Does it then follow that 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_{nk}<\infty$$
if (and only if)
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_{nk}<\infty ?$$

Comment: I guess if you take $b_{nk}$ such that the double sum converges, and set $a_{nk}=b_{nk}$ for $n>1$, $a_{1,k}=1$, the answer would be no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider as counterexample

$$a_{nk}=\frac{1}{n^2k^2}$$

$$b_{nk}=\frac{1}{n^2k^2}+\frac k {n^3}$$